# how to use azure cognitive search for reading match from web links?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-search

We are working on chatbot using microsoft bot framework. have got a use case to read the content from websites via azure search. Can we use azure search for reading content from websites? can you share any reference url? these websites contains PDF links also , we need to read content from these PDF links also.

Comment: You already asked exactly the same question which was rejected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890053/can-we-use-azure-search-for-reading-content-from-websites

Comment: but looks like that is still in closed status even after editing the content. and that question is deleted. this new question is now focused on one problem only.

Comment: Yes but that's not a programming issue